# Sending XML file in Soap call with elements in variables - Robot Framework

Tags: python, xml, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm automating tests using Robot Framework (Libraries XML and Soap)) and i have a big doubt...

I have the following XML file (.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datas>
    <data id="person">
        <phone>83910388</price>
        <name>Test</name>
    </data id>
</datas>
```

I would like to leave a dynamic data (variable) in my "phone" and "name" attribute.
This variable would be filled in my test case, through the Faker Library.

Can I do this? As?

I've tried several ways, like the example below, but all without success... =/

```
*** Variables ***
${PHONE}    928466190

*** Test Cases ***

Test XML
    ${file}    Parse Xml    ${path_to_file}
    
    ${element}    Get Element Attribute    ${file}    //datas

    Set Element Attribute    ${element}    phone    ${PHONE}
```

Can I do this? As?

I've tried it in different ways. I used the keyword "Set Element Attribute", for example. This keyword adds dynamic data but is not saved inside the file and sent.

Thanks very much!!!!

Comment: Parfait, sorry.
I forgot to include my example.
Updated the description!

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq.  You have typos in your xml that I corrected.  Also when reading from a File use Load instead of Parse.  You original code was not correct and used Parse instead of load.

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$xml = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datas>
    <data id="person">
        <phone>83910388</phone>
        <name>Test</name>
    </data>
</datas>
'@
 $doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse([string]$xml)
$phone = $doc.Descendants().Where( {$_.Name.LocalName -eq "phone"})
$phone = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Last($phone)
$phone.Value = "1234567"
$data
$doc.Save(Filename)
```